# How to properly escape shell arguments on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, command-line, ffmpeg

I am trying to properly escape user supplied data for a command line script. Normally I would use [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php), however this will simply not work because it's breaks the eventual command line in glorious ways.

The use case is trying to add meta data to videos using ffmpeg. A simplified and isolated problem case is the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -metadata author="My Name" out.mp4
```

The author value is user supplied (`My Name`). I tried escaping only the user supplied part which resulted in:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -metadata author=""My Name"" out.mp4
```

Which results in the following ffmpeg error:

> Name: Invalid argument

Next I tried escaping the entire flag (`-metadata author="My Name"`) which results in:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 "-metadata author= My Name " out.mp4
```

> "Unrecognized option 'metadata author= My Name '.

**Test cases:**

```
$flag = '-metadata author="%s"';

var_dump(sprintf($flag, escapeshellarg('My Name')));
var_dump(escapeshellarg(sprintf($flag, 'My Name')));
```

Is there anything that will properly escape the user supplied data so that users cannot pass arbitrary flags to my command *and* that will make ffmpeg happy without having to do it manually with the risk of forgetting something and screwing it up?

**Update**

I also tried escaping the entire flag value which works unless there is a double quote inside the user supplied part:

```
$flag = 'author="%s"';

var_dump('-metadata ' . escapeshellarg(sprintf($flag, 'My Name')));
var_dump('-metadata ' . escapeshellarg(sprintf($flag, 'My "Name"')));
```

Which results in:

```
-metadata "author= My Name "
-metadata "author= My  Name  " // it eats my quotes
```

Comment: Assuming that `ffmpeg` uses the Microsoft C runtime to parse the command line (this may depend on how it was built) you can embed quotes by doubling them, e.g., `-metadata "author=My ""Name"""`.  Most other characters are already safe inside quote marks.  However, it would probably be safer and simpler to use a [preset file](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Preset-files) rather than including user-supplied data on the command line.  (The *correct* solution is to use a library rather than an executable, but I don't know if `ffmpeg` supports this.)